# R Data.table. Need modify column using grouping and complex conditional filtering

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, filtering, grouping

Here is data sample:

```
zz <- "
id  Sub_Segment1    Sub_Segment2    Sub_Segment3    Sub_Segment4    Sub_Segment5
1   x   x1  r   y1  z1
1   x   x1  r   y1  z1
1   x   x1  r   y1  z1
1   x   x1  r   y1  z1
1   x   x1  r   y1  z1
1   x   x1  r   y1  z1
1   x   x1  r   y1  z1
2   y   x2  r   y2  z1
2   y   x2  r   y2  z1
2   y   x2  r   y2  z1
2   y   x2  r   y2  z1
2   y   x2  r   y2  z1
"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
setDT(Data)
```

If I apply my modification to the whole table it returns NA:

```
Data[(length(unique(Sub_Segment1[Sub_Segment1!=""]))==1),name:="test" , by=id ]
```

returns:

```
 id Sub_Segment1 Sub_Segment2 Sub_Segment3 Sub_Segment4 Sub_Segment5 name
 1:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1   NA
 2:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1   NA
 3:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1   NA
 4:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1   NA
 5:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1   NA
 6:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1   NA
 7:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1   NA
 8:  2            y           x2            r           y2           z1   NA
 9:  2            y           x2            r           y2           z1   NA
10:  2            y           x2            r           y2           z1   NA
11:  2            y           x2            r           y2           z1   NA
12:  2            y           x2            r           y2           z1   NA
```

But if I take only one sample with constant value in subsegment it works:

```
new_data = Data[id ==1]
new_data[(length(unique(Sub_Segment1[Sub_Segment1!=""]))==1),name:="test" , by=id ]
```

returns correct

```
   id Sub_Segment1 Sub_Segment2 Sub_Segment3 Sub_Segment4 Sub_Segment5 name
1:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1 test
2:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1 test
3:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1 test
4:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1 test
5:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1 test
6:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1 test
7:  1            x           x1            r           y1           z1 test
```

and

```
Data[id ==1,(length(unique(Sub_Segment1[Sub_Segment1!=""]))==1) ] # returns TRUE
```

How should I modify code to apply my function to the every group of dataset in data.table way?

Comment: The problem is that in your modification, you do: `(length(unique(Sub_Segment1[Sub_Segment1!=""]))==1)`, which doesn't match any rows for me.

Comment: @ira it should match if group_by applied, but it is not

Comment: so you want to apply the filter condition on each group from the group by?

Comment: @ira right, I want apply filter condition and modification on filtered data

Comment: The i-expression in data.table doesn't operate by group

Comment: @docendodiscimus =( is there way to apply such filter in j-expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the identification of the rows which you want to edit into the part of the command, where you select columns:

```
# load data table package
library(data.table)
# create the data table from string
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
setDT(Data)
# group by and adjust where condition is matched
Data[, name := ifelse(length(unique(Sub_Segment1[Sub_Segment1!=""])) == 1, "test", NA) , by=id ]
```

Instead of ifelse, you could also make your modifications everywhere and then filter, or use join operation.

Comment: Since you need to compute this only once per group, I would suggest using `if ..  else` instead of `ifelse`. Plus, you could use data.table's `uniqueN` to keep the code short. `Data[, name := if(uniqueN(Sub_Segment1[Sub_Segment1 != ""]) == 1) "test" else NA, by = id]`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also: `Data[, name := "test"[uniqueN(Sub_Segment1[Sub_Segment1!=""]) == 1], by = "id"]`